# Updating a github repository that was created using the web interfaces import functionality

Tags: git, github

I have a GitHub repository that was imported into an organizations GitHub account using the import option in Github's web interface. I need to update this repository every now and again. The repository I personally have gets updated regularly.

Is there a way of having changes automatically cloned into the organizations repository or possibly just a quick method of using the web interfaces import functionality to just drag a copy of the repository down again without having to delete the repository each time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are working on the same repository as the one imported into the organization (meaning same history of commits), you could add that organization repo as a remote to your local repo (in addition of your current "origin").

Then you can push in one command to both:

- origin
- orga repo

See "[Pushing to Multiple Git Repos](https://gist.github.com/rvl/c3f156e117e22a25f242)" as an example.

```
git remote set-url --add --push origin git@github.com:<you>/<repo>.git
git remote set-url --add --push origin git@bitbucket.org:<orga>/<repo>.git
```

(Assuming you are a collaborator in that organization)